# How do I get a List of Containers Name from Blob with Azure Storage Blobs?

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

I found some ansewrs using WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob, but this package is depreciated.

So I need to get a list of containers in a Blob Storage from Azure using .net core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add 'Azure.Storage.Blobs' NuGet package.

Use BlobServiceClient class

```
string connectionString = "";
BlobServiceClient client = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
```

Use GetBlobContainers or GetBlobContainersAsync to retrieve the containers:

```
//-------------------------------------------------
// List containers
//-------------------------------------------------
async static Task ListContainers(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient, 
                                string prefix, 
                                int? segmentSize)
{
    string continuationToken = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        do
        {
            // Call the listing operation and enumerate the result segment.
            // When the continuation token is empty, the last segment has been returned
            // and execution can exit the loop.
            var resultSegment = 
                blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainersAsync(BlobContainerTraits.Metadata, prefix, default)
                .AsPages(continuationToken, segmentSize);
            await foreach (Azure.Page<BlobContainerItem> containerPage in resultSegment)
            {
                foreach (BlobContainerItem containerItem in containerPage.Values)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Container name: {0}", containerItem.Name);
                }

                // Get the continuation token and loop until it is empty.
                continuationToken = containerPage.ContinuationToken;

                Console.WriteLine();
            }

        } while (continuationToken != string.Empty);
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        throw;
    }
}
```

prefix param is optional in case you want to search for the containers that start with some prefix.

The code comes from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-containers-list?tabs=dotnet):